# Simple wireless connection between two circuits

Tags: wireless

I'm relatively new to robotics, and I'm building a project for which I need a simple wireless connection between two circuits such that when the first circuit is switched on, the other circuit gets switched on too. I'm looking to preferably build something like this on my own, but I have no idea about wireless connections. I only know basic wired robotics. I also know C++ programming if that helps. Apologies if such a question has already been asked.

Regards,
Hanit Banga

Comment: Can you share some enviormental information about your setup: How far are the curcuits seperated? Is anything  (wall, house) between those curcuits? This information are needed to evalute which wireless technology can be used.

Comment: It's a very basic project, the circuits will be no further apart than 2-3 metres with only air between them

Comment: Are the circuits fixed in place?

Comment: Infra-red, radio-frequency, bluetooth or wifi.
To start off, you might want to get a cabled connection working and then try to expand it to wireless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the curcuits are placed stationary the most simplistic solution might be using an IR-Led and a reciever. Like the :
http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1835437.pdf 
http://wwwtest.vishay.com/docs/81007/tsal5100.pdf

Just powerup the Led. The reciever will recognize this light and switches the output.

Comment: +1 for basically what I was writing (you beat me to it!). [There's also a goood tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/ir-sensor/making-an-intervalometer) about using IR with Arduino.

Comment: That wouldn't work for me, as the circuits will not be stationary, but if nothing else, I'll try this as this seems to be simple enough.

Comment: The tutorial I linked to should work for you; the transmitter (LED) and receiver (IR sensor) don't have to be pointed directly at each other, just like your TV remote doesn't have to be pointed directly at your TV. They just need to be in the same room.

Comment: If the curcuits are something like robots and moving around then IR-Communication might not be the best solution. Maybe I add another solution later

Comment: I think this will work if it is similar to TV remote, as one of the circuits will be completely stationary, while the other will move about a little, mostly changing orientation, not position. So I'll most probably go with this. Thanks for your help

Comment: So if I connect the LED to my main circuit, when it switches on the receiver will allow current to pass through? Which two ends of the receiver do I need to connect in my circuit?

Answer (score 0):

First of all do it with IR transmiter and receiver to develop your skills on signal buffering and processing. Than try to do it with fm or am transceiver circuits. Also you can use toy remote control devices 25MHz or 433 MHz.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an implementation that would use a microcontroller, you can opt for RF which allows a much broader range of communication then IR can offer.

Sparfun offers some transmitters and recievers for use $4/5/ea.

[Transmitter](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10534)
[Receiver](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10532)

Comment: In my opinion your approach might be an overkill for this requirement. Basically he needs to transmit only one bit.